# How to display one dot every second in C before quitting the process?

Tags: c, printf, buffer, sleep

I am trying to display **...** (three dots), but each dot then a second delay then a second dot then a second delay then a third dot.

I tried this

```
for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{
sleep(1);
printf(".");
sleep(1);
}
```

But this just waits for 6 seconds and then prints the three dots all together but I don't want that. Is there a fix for this. I want

**.** second delay **.** second delay **.**

but it will appear

**...**

Comment: fflush() may be needed or something that makes sure that buffered output is displayed.

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` before you leave to go to sleep.

Comment: And apparently it will do every 2 seconds, as you have 2 sleeps around the print...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

`printf()` prints to `stdout` which is bufferred. Flush out the buffer after each `printf()`.

`<< std::flush;` is the C++ equivalent to this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Linux or Windows?

If you are on Windows, the function called should be

```
Sleep(1000);
```

This is because Windows treat its "Sleep" function as in milliseconds, that is x * 1000 where 'x' is the amount of seconds you want your program to tick. Your example was every second, therefor you say 1 * 1000 which is 1000, so the function should be as described above, to make your program tick every second.

Here's the full code.

```
#include <windows.h>
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        //Sleep(1000); pre-pause 1 second before print 
        printf(".");
        //Sleep(1000); post-pause 1 second after print
    }
}
```